# What If the announcement for a Tenure-Track position in a research-intensive university does not request a research statement?

Tags: career-path, statement-of-purpose, tenure-track, faculty-application

If a TT position is announced in  a medical-related field in a research-intensive university, and they request to apply using 1) a letter of interest and 2) a CV (No research statement is required). They say the candidate's time would be divided between research 60%, teaching 20%, and service 20%. Would you still submit a research statement or would you just include in the letter of interest more details about your current and future research (this might require making the letter little longer ~3 pages)?

Comment: What country is this?  What field?

Comment: Thank you very much for those submitted answers for my question. I have contacted the search committee Chair as suggested below, and he recommended submitting a separate research statement.

Comment: I always assumed an ad like this meant: "The successful candidate will have a strong enough research program that people here have already heard of them and are familiar with their major research accomplishments". I'd be interested if someone with hiring experience can confirm or deny.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a three page letter of interest would not be abnormal in these circumstances. Please keep the font size large given that the faculty on search committees have aging eyes.

My guess is that they've gotten over 200 applications for a single position in previous years and are attempting to do a first cull before asking for more details and letters. They should be commended.

Comment: Thanks a lot RoboKaren, our senior colleagues input is always helpful!

Comment: _My guess is that they've gotten over 200 applications for a single position in previous years_ — Speaking from personal experience: As opposed to what?

Comment: Back when we only got forty or fifty applications and when everything was done by postal mail, it was easier to have the entire portfolio up front. Now that the number of applications has exploded and given the ease of asking for supplementary material later on, the better search committees have reduced the upfront burden. No point in asking for letters from 200x3 people = 600 separate letters for example, if a good 80-90% of applications will be rejected in the first cull.

Comment: The point in getting the letters is that you can use them to make the first cut: they are one of the most important parts of the application.  Similarly, I don't get the commendability of not asking for the research statement straightaway.  If you have the research statement at the beginning, you can look at it sooner or you can look at it later: your choice.  What you're asking the OP to do sounds like *more* work for him: a semi-personalized piece of a research statement.

Comment: I don't think the committee would be put off by a one page cover letter with research statement appended if that is easier on the OP. The OP doesn't list her discipline but separate research statements are not the norm in all disciplines for entry level positions, especially some humanities and social sciences. I didn't write one until my third year review...

Comment: Letters are important but a good percentage of applications can be culled without them (wrong field, wrong discipline, wrong research area,  wrong level, no degree, etc.).

Comment: As usual, it would be very helpful if the OP clarified what discipline this is.  (I asked...) For instance, in my discipline and at my public research university, it would be a poor showing to only get 300 applications for a tenure-track position.  Most of our jobs are not further targeted within mathematics (though this is starting to change a bit), and the percentage of applications we receive which are in the right discipline, an acceptable research area, and with the right degree is probably at least 80%.

Comment: Come to think of it, I had no idea that for TT applications in the humanities at research universities, research statements are not standard.  That's quite interesting (you always assume that others do things your way until you learn otherwise).  So in what part of the application is the information about the candidate's research conveyed?  If the answer is "cover letter", we will really be living in different worlds: you might find it interesting that within recent memory I asked my department head to include cover letters as a part of the application materials: it's that peripheral for us.

Comment: Cover letter. Then, later on, we'll ask for the dissertation. In the humanities and humanistic social sciences, it's not as easy to summarize one's research in a few paragraphs or e=mc^2 .

Comment: Well, FYI: research statements (for research jobs; some liberal arts colleges ask for shorter "research summaries") generally start at five pages and get longer as the candidate gets more senior.  The challenge of shoehorning one's work into this small number of pages is indeed, um, challenging.

Comment: Is it possible that this is job ad that isn't really a job ad?  In other words, the department already knows who they want to hire, but for legal reasons, they have to post a job ad.

Comment: It's always a possibility but impossible to discern just from this. Even with an internal candidate, they usually have to go by the book.

Answer (score 2):

Call or e-mail the search committee chair to ask; the chair almost certainly handles these kinds of questions routinely.  The chair may tell you that the committee wants your research information in your cover letter; or they may not care where in the package your research information is located; or they are not collecting research information at this time (although this is quite unlikely for a 60% research position).